# Can I use Google Api for adding/remove user for GoogleDrive

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a tasc - "Share GoogleDrive files for some users (with gmail accounts)", and then remove somebody from GoogleDrive with post/get request

Can I some use this with API(PHP)?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*[Create a permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) and assign it to a file using a `POST` request the Drive API. You can also remove someone with a [`DELETE` request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/delete).*

#### More Information:

You can use the [Google API PHP client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to authenticate as a user and access Google Drive from PHP. A Quickstart to help you get set up can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php).

You will need to create the permission resource before attaching it to a file:

```php
// Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$fileId = "SOME_FILE_ID";

$userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
    'type' => 'user',
    'role' => 'writer',
    'emailAddress' => 'someone@domain.com'
  ));

$results = $service->permissions->create($fileId, $userPermission);
```

and to delete:

```
$results = $service->permissions->delete($fileId, $permissionId);
```

#### References:

- [Permissions | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions)
- [Permissions: create | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)
- [Permissions: delete | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/delete)
- [GitHub - googleapis/google-api-php-client: A PHP client library for accessing Google APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)
- [PHP Quickstart | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php)